# Converting Angular 4 App to PWA

Tags: javascript, angular, progressive-web-apps

I've set some routing rules in ngsw-manifest.json as shown below. Problem is when I'm running a http-server and directly hitting http://localhost:8080/home it's showing url not found.

```
{
 "static.ignore": [
   "^\/assets\/ignore.*$"
 ],
  "routing": {
   "index": "/index.html",
   "routes": {
     "/": {
       "match": "exact"
     },
     "/home": {
       "match": "exact"
     },
     "/listing/must_watch_videos": {
       "match": "exact"
     },
     "^/regex/.*/route$": {
       "match": "regex"
     }
   }
 },
   "external": {
    "urls": [
        {
            "url": "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Comment: have you found a solution? im stuck at the same issue.

Comment: @FlorianWidtmann it's working when I've deployed my application on server by maintaining an Etag, but it's not working locally

Comment: The question is about a specific problem and not about converting an existing angular app to a PWA. Please consider changing the title of the question.

Answer (score 0):

When someone requests /home your server can't find a file or folder with that name and returns error 404. You need your server to instead server your main app .html as though it resides at those locations.

For node http-server it looks like the option would be `--spa`.  For example:

`ws --spa index.html`

> Single Page Application
>
> Serving a Single Page Application (an app with
>   client-side routing, e.g. a React or Angular app) is as trivial as
>   specifying the name of your single page:
>
> $ ws --spa index.html Serving at http://mbp.local:8000,
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000, http://192.168.0.100:8000 By default, requests
>   for typical SPA paths (e.g. /user/1, /login) return 404 Not Found as a
>   file at that location does not exist. By marking index.html as the SPA
>   you create this rule:
>
> If a static file is requested (e.g. /css/style.css) then serve it, if
>   not (e.g. /login) then serve the specified SPA and handle the route
>   client-side.

See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-web-server#single-page-application

See: https://github.com/lwsjs/local-web-server/wiki/How-to-serve-a-Single-Page-Application-(SPA)

Comment: No it's not returning index.html. Yea that is the behaviour I'm expecting but it's not working

Comment: It's working when my chrome browser console is close

Comment: What server / platform are you using?

Comment: I'm using node http-server. Right now I'm testing it locally

Comment: Have you setup SPA routing?  Please see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-web-server#single-page-application